# How to Turn Off New User Notification Emails in WordPress only for admin

Tags: wordpress

I am using `register_new_user` action to disable the email notification for admin but when a user register's it still generates an email to admin.

I am using **Gravity Forms** for User Registration

Here is my code.

```
remove_action('register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications');
add_action('register_new_user', 'ecpd_send_new_user_notifications');

function ecpd_send_new_user_notifications($user_id, $notify = 'user') {
    wp_new_user_notification($user_id, null, $notify);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think Gravity form plugin is overwrite your default settings. First of all, as I know, you can tudn of the admin notification at the dashboard for default notification emails.

You can turn it of by gravity form settings:

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/configuring-notifications-in-gravity-forms/

You can also use hooks on `gform_notification`. Reference is here:

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_notification/

Comment: but i want to let you know that i haven't created any notification in gravity forms even i have used the filter (add_filter( 'gform_disable_notification', 'disable_notification', 10, 4 );) to disabled the gravity form notifications  but still i am getting admin notifications.

Comment: i asked to gravity form support and they said "Those emails are sent by WordPress, they are not sent by Gravity Forms."

Comment: when i am trying to register user by using wordpress default register method there is no admin email generated for admin because i am using action (remove_action('register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications');) but when i am trying to register user by using gravity forms register form then admin notification fires but that notification is not from gravity forms (gravity forms support said)

Comment: Try to do nothing at here: `function ecpd_send_new_user_notifications($user_id, $notify = 'admin') {
    return false;
}`

Comment: still sending email notifications to admin

Comment: remove_action('register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications');
add_action('register_new_user', 'ecpd_send_new_user_notifications');
function ecpd_send_new_user_notifications($user_id, $notify = 'user'){
    wp_new_user_notification($user_id, null, $notify);
}

Comment: according to this action only user should get notified and that is actually happening but only when i am trying to register user with wordpress default register method

Comment: I have found something in gravity forms user registration add-on there is a file with name class-gf-user-registration.php where new_user_notification function is used to notify admin and user i just want to remove admin notification from there. But i don't want to make changes in plugin or add-on i want hook so that i can make changes in functions.php of my theme

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY figured it out...

1. Create a file disable-new-user-emails.php
2. Insert the following code

   ```
   <?php /*
   Plugin Name:  Disable New User Email Notifications
   Description:  Using GravityForms Registration Add-on and Custom Notifications? This will Disable the Default WordPress Admin and User Notifications.
   Author:       BeHappy in 2017
    */

   if ( ! function_exists( 'gf_new_user_notification' ) ) {
       function gf_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '', $notify = '' ) {
                   return;
               }
           }
   ?>
   ```
3. Save it!!!
4. Upload it to your /wp-content/plugins folder
5. Activate the plugin
6. NO MORE [SITE] New User Registration Emails! :D

**Note**: We are using the GravityForms User Registration Add-on. In order for admin or users to receive a registration / welcome email, you have to create notifications for them in the form's **Settings > Notifications**

**Note**: This will also prevent the email containing the username and password to the new user should you have your registration form set to auto generate a user password.

Lastly, I'm also running a MultiSite... I have the Settings > Registration notification unticked. I'm sure this same code will work for a single WP site.

- Confirmed working on a single/standalone install of WP.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, placed in a plugin inside the plugins/mu-plugins folder:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_new_user_notification' ) ) {
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = null, $notify = '' ) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Previously, I used it in functions.php and it didn't work, but apparently, when placed inside another plugin it overrides other plugins that are also calling this function.